# Removing Character String from File Name

Tags: powershell

We’ve run into a situation where we need to bulk remove a string of characters from a large list of file names.  The string of characters that needs to be removed is the same for every file, but I’m having some trouble writing out a command that will work.  I have a feeling it’s due to all of the special characters that are in the file name.  This is what I’ve come up with so far, but it doesn’t work properly:

Get-ChildItem -Path ‘E:\data\management\2016 401k Profit Sharing from Kesha.xlsx.id[8C00Ea7D-0001].[gabbiemciveen@aol.com].phobos’; | rename-item -newname { $_.FullName -replace “.id[8C00Ea7D-0001].[gabbiemciveen@aol.com].phobos”,”” }

It runs the command without erroring but for some reason it does not actually remove the string “.id[8C00Ea7D-0001].[gabbiemciveen@aol.com].phobos” from the end of the file name.

Any assistance you can lend is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Replace uses Regular Expression so there are several characters that need to be escaped with "\" to be taken literally, at least outside char classes:

- Brackets: []
- Parentheses: ()
- Curly braces: {}
- Operators: *, +, ?, |
- Anchors: ^, $
- Others: ., \

Use this for a Single Item, like the one in your question:

```
 Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath 'E:\data\management\2016 401k Profit Sharing from Kesha.xlsx.id[8C00Ea7D-0001].[gabbiemciveen@aol.com].phobos' | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name -replace ".id\[8C00Ea7D-0001\]\.\[gabbiemciveen@aol\.com\]\.phobos"}
```

Also, use LiteralPath with Get-ChildItem to ensure no characters are interpreted as wildcards if they're present.

Use this for a directory wide rename:

```
 Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath 'E:\data\management\' -Filter *[8C00Ea7D-0001].[gabbiemciveen@aol.com].phobos | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name -replace ".id\[8C00Ea7D-0001\]\.\[gabbiemciveen@aol\.com\]\.phobos"}
```

Note that Filter does not use Regular Expression.

Comment: How would we go about making it wildcard so that it replaces *.id\[8C00Ea7D-0001\]\.\[gabbiemciveen@aol\.com\]\.phobos across the entire directory.

Comment: I've updated the answer to include the entire directory command, if this solves your problem please mark it as the accepted answer.